# Why don't I see packets when I listen on my ftp port with tcpdump on localhost?

Tags: ftp, tcpdump

I'm accessing my localhost ftp server by Iceweasel or by the terminal (with the command `ftp`) while listening on the ftp port with

```
sudo tcpdump -vv -A 'port 20'
```

or

```
sudo tcpdump -vv -A port ftp
```

but nothing is printed although the connection is well established.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the FTP command TCP connections are on port 21 (ftp is 21) not 20.

Comment: You may also have an ftp "passive" connection, meaning that your client will open a second connection to the server with high port numbers, contrary to an "active" ftp-connection where your client opens a control-channel to the client on port 21 and the server opens a connection to your client on port 20 for the data (which is not possible behind a firewall)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You indicated you are connecting via localhost. You will probably need to specify the interface with -i lo (or lo0 on a Mac), so use:

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo -vv -A port ftp
```

or on a Mac:

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo0 -vv -A port ftp
```

The you should see the traffic. The reason:

> `-i`     Listen on interface.  If unspecified, tcpdump searches the system interface list for the lowest numbered, configured up interface (excluding loopback), which may turn out to be, for example, "eth0".

Comment: You may also want to add `-n` as hostname resolution can delay the printing.

Comment: "or lo0 on a Mac" ...or on most other UN\*Xes - Linux is the exception here.